# NEO4J - Matching a path where middle node might exist or not

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph:

[image]

I would look to get all contractors and subcontractors and clients, starting from David.
So I thought of a query likes this:

`MATCH (a:contractor)-[*0..1]->(b)-[w:works_for]->(c:client) return a,b,c`

This would return:

```
(0:contractor {name:"David"})   (0:contractor {name:"David"})   (56:client {name:"Sarah"})
(0:contractor {name:"David"})   (1:subcontractor {name:"John"}) (56:client {name:"Sarah"})
```

Which returns the desired result. The issue here is performance.
If the DB contains millions of records and I leave (b) without a label, the query will take forever. If I add a label to `(b)` such as `(b:subcontractor)` I won't hit millions of rows but I will only get results with subcontractors:

`(0:contractor {name:"David"})    (1:subcontractor {name:"John"}) (56:client {name:"Sarah"})`

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

link to graph example: https://console.neo4j.org/r/pry01l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things to consider with your query.
The relationship type is not specified- is it the case that the only relationships from `contractor` nodes are `works_for` and `hired`? If not, you should constrain the relationship types being matched in your query. For example

```
MATCH (a:contractor)-[:works_for|:hired*0..1]->(b)-[w:works_for]->(c:client) 
RETURN a,b,c
```

The fact that (b) is unlabelled does not mean that every node in the graph will be matched. It will be reached either as a result of traversing the `works_for` or `hired` relationships if specified, or any relationship from `:contractor`, or via the `works_for` relationship.

If you do want to label it, and you have a hierarchy of types, you can assign multiple labels to nodes and just use the most general one in your query. For example, you could have a label such as `ExternalStaff` as the generic label, and then further add `Contractor` or `SubContractor` to distinguish individual nodes. Then you can do something like

```
MATCH (a:contractor)-[:works_for|:hired*0..1]->(b:ExternalStaff)-[w:works_for]->(c:client) 
RETURN a,b,c
```

Depends really on your use cases.

Comment: Thanks, [:works_for|:hired] seems to do the trick (This syntax is deprecated and is now written [:works_for|hired]). Regarding adding a new generic label, it's not possible in our current architecture. Is there another possibility?